# Existence of bijections in $L$

Tags: set-theory

Let $A, B \in L$ (where $L$ is the class of constructible sets). Is the following true (and why)?

> If there is a bijection $f \colon A \to B$, then there is a bijection $g \in L$ such that $g \colon A \to B$.

Comment: Why did you write $g\in L$? $L$ is the class of the constructible sets, but $g$ is not a set but a function.

Comment: @Angelo Functions are sets.

Comment: @Angelo Everything is a set in ZF. Every function is a set of kuratowksi pairs.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What's the difference between $f$ and $g$ ?

Comment: @TomCollinge $f$ may not be in $L$.

Comment: Then what is your definition of $f$ ?

Comment: The function $f$ is in $V$, i.e. in the class of all sets (in a model of ZF). On the other hand, $g$ is in $L$ which is the class of all constructible sets.

Comment: Are we talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_set_(topology) ? in which case, what topology is involved ?

Comment: @TomCollinge No, we are talking about [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe).

Comment: Not an area I'm familiar with. I'll be interested to see the answer. Hope you get one soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. It is consistent with ZFC that the first ordinal that is uncountable in $L$, usually written $\omega_1^{(L)}$, is countable.  That is, $\omega_1^{(L)}<\omega_1$.  In this situation, there is a bijection from $\omega_1^{(L)}$ to $\omega$, but there is no such bijection in $L$.  (The phrase to look up for proofs of this consistency is "cardinal collapsing".)

Comment: I would write it as $\omega_1^L$. James Cummings prefers $(\omega_1)_L$. I do not remember seeing the $\omega_1^{(L)}$ notation, though.