# The ordinals accidentally written on the initial segment of length $\omega$ at the output tape of Ordinal Turing Machines

Tags: logic, set-theory, ordinals

This question implies that (i) all [Ordinal Turing Machines](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0502264) start the computation with empty input and no parameters; (ii) we have fixed a particular way to encode an ordinal by an infinite binary sequence (a real).

According to part (iii) of Definition 3.10 in the paper [“Recognizable sets and Woodin cardinals: Computation beyond the constructible universe”](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.06101), a real $x$ is *accidentally writable* if there is an OTM-program $P$ with empty input such that $x$ is written on the initial segment of length $\gamma$ of the tape [does “the tape” mean *the output tape*?] at some time. But I want to ask about reals accidentally written on the initial segment of length $\omega$ (the smallest limit ordinal) of the output tape at some time $\tau$, assuming that $\tau$ is not necessarily countable. I will call such reals (or ordinals encoded by reals) “accidentally $\omega$-writable”.

I have read that the accidentally writable reals are exactly the reals in $L$ (part 3 of Lemma 3.13 in the linked paper). Does this imply that the supremum of accidentally $\omega$-writable ordinals is equal to $\omega_1$?

If the answer is “yes”, I need an explanation of why this is possible (that is, how an OTM writes an encoding of an arbitrarily large countable ordinal on the initial $\omega$-segment of the output tape starting from empty input with no parameters). If the answer is “no”, how large is the supremum of accidentally $\omega$-writable ordinals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the sentence "just before" definition-3.10 then you will see the expression $x \subseteq \gamma$. So if $\gamma$ is some ordinal then it seems to me that the author(s) are talking about some subset $x$ of the $\gamma$. That is a set of ordinals whose where each individual ordinal must be less than $\gamma$. So to define "accidentally writeable reals" specifically, you just need to set $\gamma=\omega$ (in definition-3.10 for the paper you linked).

Further regarding this point:

> But I want to ask about reals accidentally written on the initial segment of length $\omega$ (the smallest limit ordinal) of the output tape at some time $\tau$, assuming that $\tau$ is not necessarily countable. I will call such reals (or ordinals encoded by reals) “accidentally $\omega$-writable”.

It seems that no new accidentally writeable real can be generated at some time $\geq \omega_1$. That's because if it was possible, then given some specific real number as input to OTM, it would be possible to halt at some time $\geq \omega_1$, which is impossible **[** for this, start enumerating all accidentally writeable reals and when a new accidentally written real matches the "input real" then halt **]**. For this, I don't know the reason, but I think that the answer to one of your older questions is relevant in this regard https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372051. I am assuming that the answer given is correct (since I don't understand it).

**Edit:** Sorry I misremembered the reference I was talking about.

Regarding this point:

> I have read that the accidentally writable reals are exactly the reals in $L$ (part 3 of Lemma 3.13 in the linked paper). Does this imply that the supremum of accidentally $\omega$-writable ordinals is equal to $ω_1$?

This should be equal to $\omega^L_1$. It is consistent with set theory that $\omega^L_1=\omega_1$. It is also consistent that $\omega^L_1 \neq \omega_1$. I don't know the reason, but the answer in this question seems to mention this: [Existence of bijections in $L$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4132950/existence-of-bijections-in-l).

Comment: "No new accidentally writeable real can be generated at some time $\geq \omega_1$" -- yes, I know that. I wrote "not necessarily countable" for the single reason of that restricting $\tau$ to be countable is redundant because it does not affect the set of accidentally $\omega$-writable reals. So, the answer to the basic question is "yes", as I expected. But _how_ can an OTM accidentally write an arbitrarily large countable ordinal starting from empty input with no parameters?

Comment: See the "first" theorem in this answer (to one of my older questions): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345007/relation-between-eta-and-omegal-1

Comment: *"So, the answer to the basic question is "yes", as I expected."* The answer may be yes or may not be yes. That is, supremum of accidentally writeable reals might be equal to $\omega_1$ or it might be $<\omega_1$. Both are consistent (with set theory).

Comment: The word "yes" in the sentence [So, the answer to the basic question is "yes", as I expected] means "yes, the supremum of accidentally $\omega$-writable reals is $\omega_1$ if $\omega^L_1=\omega_1$." Thank you, the situation is more clear to me now.